# Pull all item from Message queue

Tags: c++, sockets, message-queue

There is an application which connect to multiple sockets. It has two threads, receiving thread and processing  thread. So in between them, I create a message queue. Since it does not require to process the message one by one, all the messages can be pulled from the queue and then update the internal data structure. Finally, start to process. Currently, I create my own message queue. I am just wondering if there is any better option. ps performance is critical

EDIT: Better means good performance, easy to use and guarantee delivery. optional: use zeromq to do so.

Comment: You may want to define "better" with a little more clarity. Lots of things can make a msgq "better", unless they're not things you care about (like guaranteed delivery, for example).

Comment: Q: By "create my own message queue", I guess you're *not* using any standard library like SysV message queues, Microsoft Message Queues or WCF, or rabbitmq.  Correct?

Comment: yes. just use std::deque and boost::mutex to create the message queue. Btw, The application is running on Linux platform.

Comment: Your application will be network-bound. Performance of a properly implemented data structure will not be the rate-determining step. Worry about something else.

Comment: Yes. I concern more about context switch.

Comment: Wrong again, you should be concerned mostly about network performance.

Comment: But network performance is not a big concern as they are just IPC sockets in a local machine.